# SOQL cross object query to call externally

Tags: soql, integration, informatica

I need some help creating a SOQL query or confirmation that it cannot be done. The requirements are as follows:

1. Custom Object 1 has a relation to Cases.
2. Custom Object 2 has a relation to Cases.
3. Selection criteria for the query are available only in Custom Object 1.
4. I need all of Custom Object 2 related to the Cases that are related to the selected list of Custom Object 1.
5. It needs to be done in a single SOQL query.

This will be called using Informatica and I do not have permission to make changes to the schemas or processes in Salesforce to make this simpler. I also do not have access to a database to sync with Custom Object 2 and use it as a lookup to do it cleanly in two queries. The current approach is to get all of Custom Object 2 and use it as a lookup, which is not scalable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, provided your data volume is conducive to the query not timing out. What you want is something along the lines of

```
SELECT SOME_FIELDS 
FROM Custom_Object_2__c 
WHERE Case_Id__c IN (SELECT Case_Id__c 
                     FROM Custom_Object_1__c
                     WHERE CRITERIA_ARE_TRUE)
```

This construct is called a [semi-join sub-select](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm#semijoin_and_antijoin), and it's worth noting that you can't nest them (you'll get an exciting error message).

Comment: D'oh. Can't believed I missed that. Probably worth linking to and briefly explaining [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join).

Comment: I believe the sesquipedalian name of this construct is 'semi-join sub-select', and naturally I cannot find my favorite reference link... still looking.

Comment: That's another name for it.

Comment: > sesquipedalian. That's a heck of an autological word.

Comment: I do not often get to use my Classics degree in the tech world, but when I do...